# Sqlalchemy relationship + FastApi: Вернуть значение определенного столбца

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Есть 4 модели алхимии, представляющие собой:

Коктейль, у которого есть рецепт:

```
class Cocktail(Base):
    __tablename__ = "cocktails"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String(length=100))
    image = Column(String(length=255))

    recipe = relationship("Recipe", lazy="joined")
```

Рецепт, у которого есть ингредиент, количество ингредиента и мера измерения этого количества:

```
class Recipe(Base):
    __tablename__ = "recipes"

    cocktail_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('cocktails.id'), primary_key=True, index=True)
    ingredient_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('ingredients.id'), primary_key=True)
    amount = Column(Float)
    unit_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('units.id'))

    ingredient = relationship("Ingredient", lazy="joined")
    unit = relationship("Unit", lazy="joined")
```

И соответственно, ингредиент с мерой измерения:

```
class Ingredient(Base):
    __tablename__ = "ingredients"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String(length=100), unique=True)


class Unit(Base):
    __tablename__ = "units"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String(length=10), unique=True)
```

На текущий момент, если вернуть такой объект коктейля в методе fastapi, то структура рецепта представляет собой:

```
"recipe": [
      {
        "amount": 380,
        "cocktail_id": 1,
        "ingredient_id": 9,
        "unit_id": 2,
        "unit": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "г"
        },
        "ingredient": {
          "id": 9,
          "name": "Лед в кубиках"
        }
      }
]
```

Есть ли возможность настроить relationship к ингредиенту и мере измерения у рецепта таким образом, чтобы он возвращал только name этого объекта? Например, так:

```
    "recipe": [
      {
        "amount": 380,
        "cocktail_id": 1,
        "ingredient_id": 9,
        "unit_id": 2,
        "unit_name": "г"
        "ingredient_name": "Лед в кубиках"
      }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Возможность есть, необходимо вытащить значение целевого столбца через `association_proxy` алхимии:

```
class Recipe(Base):
    __tablename__ = "recipes"

    cocktail_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('cocktails.id'), primary_key=True, index=True)
    ingredient_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('ingredients.id'), primary_key=True)
    amount = Column(Float)
    unit_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('units.id'))

    ingredient = relationship("Ingredient", viewonly=True, lazy="joined")
    ingredient_name = association_proxy("ingredient", "name")
    unit = relationship("Unit", viewonly=True, lazy="joined")
    unit_name = association_proxy("unit", "name")
```